# Elegantly do a sum of object attributes in CoffeeScript

Tags: coffeescript

I have an array of items like so:

```
@items = [
  {price: 12, quantity:1}, 
  {price: 4, quantity:1}, 
  {price: 8, quantity:1}
]
```

And I am looking for something like this:

```
sumPrice: ->
  @items.sum (item) -> item.price * item.quantity
```

Or anything as close as possible to this, that makes it super-easy for everyone reading the code to understand whats happening.

**So far I came up with:**

```
sumPrice: ->
   (items.map (a) -> a.price * a.quantity).reduce (a, b) -> a + b
```

- contains too much functional magic
- loses descriptiveness

And:

```
sumPrice: ->
   sum = 0
   for item in items
     sum += item.price * item.quantity
   sum
```

- which can be understood by novice JS/Coffee programmers
- feels a bit stupid

I love CoffeeScript so I hope there is a nicer solution to this & similar scenarios that I miss.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want to express the solution as `@items.sum (item) -> item.price * item.quantity` you can add a `sum` method to `Array`:

```
Array::sum = (fn = (x) -> x) ->
  @reduce ((a, b) -> a + fn b), 0

sum = @items.sum (item) -> item.price * item.quantity
```

Notice that i'm passing `0` as the initial value of [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) so the `fn` callback is called for every array value.

---

If you don't like extending the builtin objects, i guess you could express the sum as a single reduce elegantly if you extract the logic of calculating the total price for a single array item in its own function:

```
itemPrice = (item) -> item.price * item.quantity

sum = items.reduce ((total, item) -> total + itemPrice item), 0
```

Comment: Thanks for the implementation of sum!

Comment: @hakunin You're welcome. BTW, i forgot to mention that `sum` has the identity function as the default parameter so you can sum a list of numbers easily `[3, -4, 5].sum()` :)

Comment: I like the "named function" approach, makes the code much cleaner and self-documenting than a big pile of callbacks. I might go one step further and add another one so that I could `sumPrices = (t, i) -> t + itemPrice(i); sum = items.reduce(sumPrices, 0)`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on passing in the initial value!

Answer (score 14):

Functional style is not so bad. CoffeeScript allows you to prettify your code like this:

```
items
  .map (item) ->
    item.price * item.quantity
  .reduce (x,y) ->
    x+y
```

This code is easier for understanding than your one-liner.

If you don't like `map` you can use `for` instead. Like this:

```
(for item in items
  item.price * item.quantity)
  .reduce (x,y)->x+y
```

Or like this:

```
prods = for item in items
  item.price * item.quantity
prods.reduce (x,y)->x+y
```

Or you can add your own `sum()` method for arrays:

```
Array::sum = -> @reduce (x,y)->x+y
(item.price * item.quantity for item in items).sum()
```

Comment: The functional re-indentation looks good. I think I am keeping the dumb one though. If no one comes with nicer way to write it until tomorrow, I am accepting your answer, thanks!

Comment: It's ALL ABOUT the last one... `[1,2,3,4].sum() ## -> 10`

Answer (score 8):

You can use destructuring to simplify the code slightly:

```
sumPrice: ->
    sum = 0
    sum += price * quantity for {price, quantity} in @items
    sum
```

I don't think there's any way to get rid of the explicit initialization of `sum`. While Coffeescript's `for` loop syntax tends to help simplify code that would otherwise use `map()`, it doesn't really have anything analogous that simplifies `reduce()`-type operations, which is what `sumPrice` is doing here.

As mentioned in the comments, one advantage this solution has over a call to `reduce()` or `sum()` is that it avoids the overhead of creating and repeatedly calling a function.

Comment: Besides readability, another reason I believe this answer is superiour to the functional ones is that this compiles down to a simple for loop which is faster and better on memory than the functional approaches. It may not matter for your situation, but I personally find it even more readable so to me, it's the best of both worlds.

Answer (score 2):

```
sum = 0
value = (item) ->
  item.price * item.quantity
sum += value(item) for item in @items
```